# Hotlink Protection not working with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I have WordPress MU installed on the server and using some Mod Deflate and Caching the files and some other minor amendments in the .htaccess file and when I came across some modification for the clients, I noticed that on his server the images are served from my server.

Server Config: Plesk/CentOS - Linux Hosting

After a full research I tried placing all the available codes in the StackOverflow articles and other tutorials and sites but can't find what am doing wrong but it's not working.

**.htaccess with the hotlink regex and other rewrite rules**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<Files wp-config.php>  
       order allow,deny  
       deny from all  
</Files> 

<Files .htaccess>  
   order allow,deny  
   deny from all  
</Files> 

<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

**If I empty my .htaccess and just keep the following code it works.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Move this rule just below first `RewriteEngine On` line and to make it work.

Comment: you get index.php with 7th rule

Comment: @anubhava  I see its working when i added these rules from 2nd line and it works fine. Will you be a bit elaborative of what might be the case? In a separate answer instead of comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep this `HTTP_REFERER` above all other rules. Problem is that you have rule that is rewriting all URIs to `index.php`. Due to that rule `RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$` fails.

Complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<Files wp-config.php>  
       order allow,deny  
       deny from all  
</Files> 

<Files .htaccess>  
   order allow,deny  
   deny from all  
</Files> 

<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
```