# Preventing hotlinking and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

In [Hotlink Protection not working with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028484/hotlink-protection-not-working-with-htaccess/72832112) the problem of preventing hotlinking by means of .htaccess directives was discussed, but the answers there do not provide a solution for my problem.

This is my problem:

In https://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com/ I have the following .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?facebook.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?twitter.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ https://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com/_res/janis.jpg [NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^ads.txt$ ads_tm.php [L]

RewriteRule ^janis-joplin/(.*) /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1
```

In https://jimi-hendrix.servidor-alicante.com/_dev/test.htm I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com/_photos/wolman.gif">
<img src="https://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com/_photos/wolman.gif">
</body>
</html>
```

But in jimi-hendrix subdomain I can see the images in the janis-joplin subdomain.

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: I suggest you use the `RewriteLogging` feature the apache http server's rewrite module offers. Take a look at the module documentation to learn how to use it. The feature allows you to learn what is actually going on inside your rewrite engine while you develop your rule set.

Comment: You need to look at the HTTP request headers (for these two images) and add these to your question.

Comment: How about embedding the image in a Javascript, which would set the image to the IMG tag by ID, then have the script check it runs on your page? It would increase the file size by 33%, but HTTP compression would get it down to about the same size. Example - private.org.il/Hotlink

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the network traffic - HTTP request headers (which you can do in the browser dev tools)... is the `Referer` header being sent in the request for those images? What is the `Referer` header set to?

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://janis-joplin.servidor-alicante.com [NC]
> ```

The `Referer` header will *not* be sent (by default) in the first image request, since you are making an HTTP (insecure) request from an HTTPS (secure) page. Default browser behaviour suppresses the `Referer` header in this instance. You explicitly allow an empty `Referer` header (first *condition* above) in your "hotlinking" rule block so you would expect the first image to be displayed. (Realistically, you do need to allow an empty `Referer` header.)

It's not clear why the second image is displayed (assuming your `.htaccess` directives are being processed) without looking at the HTTP request headers (and knowing what HTTP Referrer-Policy is set on the referring page).